# Squash commits directly on feature without rebase or merge

Tags: git, git-branch, squash, git-squash

I've been reading a little about `--squash`ing commits, but they all seem to be go hand in hand with a `--rebase`.

I have a feature branch with a set of commits like this:

```
(Feature)          A --> B --> C --> D --> E --> F --> G
                  /
(Master)  M1 --> M2 --> M3
```

Suppose I want to merge back to the `Master` branch, but I want to clean up the commits on my feature first.

Is it possible to:

- Pick commit B, E and F and squash them together as one commit?

OR

- Can I only squash the commits that come in order, so squash: (A, B and C), or squash (D, E and F) etc?

Either way, can I do a squash directly on my feature, WITHOUT immidiately initializing a `Merge` or `Rebase` with it?

If so, how can I do this with Git?

Answer (score 23):

In my team's workflow we often merge with upstream in the middle of a bunch of commits, and rebasing could get ugly. I've found this helpful to squash all commits that are ahead of master down into one:

```
# Commit any working changes on branch "mybranchname", then...
git checkout master
git checkout -b mybranchname_temp
git merge --squash mybranchname
git commit -am "Message describing all squashed commits"
git branch -m mybranchname mybranchname_unsquashed
git branch -m mybranchname

# Optional cleanup:
git branch -D mybranchname_unsquashed

# If squashing already-pushed commits...
git push -f
```

Comment: Maybe you should cite this https://gist.github.com/n00neimp0rtant/9515611

Comment: Before doing the above merge master into your feature branch

Answer (score 8):

This works if the commits are local and have not been pushed yet:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~x
git commit -m "whatever"
```

Where x is the number of commits you want to squash

Not sure how this would work if the commits you want to squash are on the remote also - if that was the case you "might" need to:

```
git push -f
```

after running the above commands. The usual warnings of `git push -f` apply - if there is a need to force push make sure you do sanity checks with git log first (as a force push overwrites the code on the remote)!

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no.

Yes, you can avoid changing the parent of commit 'A' but I believe you can't avoid `git rebase`.  You can do interactive rebase on the same root:

```
git rebase -i M2 Feature
```

Then you can do whatever you want and at the end branch `Feature` will still start from commit M2.

Comment: This is what I came here for. A way to squash only certain commits within the feature branch, without involving master. Thank you!

Comment: Btw if there are any doubts about what is a M2 (base feature branch commit) in your particular case, `git merge-base <feature> <master>` might be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

**Solution**: *It is possible to squash multiple commits into single one without rebasing*. The best option is to create a new temporary branch from master, then merge the messy branch squashed in only single commit into the temporary branch, then making a pointer to it in your working branch and after delete the temporary one.

**Lets assume**:

- `master` is your master branch,
- `feature` is your messy working branch
- `temp` is your temporary branch

**How to do it?**

```
git checkout -b <temp> <master>
git merge --squash <feature>
git commit -m "your single message"
git checkout <feature>
git reset --hard <temp>
git push -f
git branch -D <temp>
```

Before:

```
(Feature)          A --> B --> C --> D --> E --> F --> G
                  /
(Master)  M1 --> M2 --> M3
```

After:

```
                           AG --> 
                          /
(Master)  M1 --> M2 --> M3
```